# encryption in node js

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I tried to insert a encrypt value to db, i can encrypt the value the encrypted value can't be inserted in db.

```
app.post('/insert', function (req, res) {

    // var Fname=req.body.fname;
    // var Lname=req.body.pwd;

    var data = {
        Fname: req.body.fname,
        Lname: req.body.Lname
    };

    function hashP(getit, cb) {
        bcrypt.genSalt(15, function (err, salt) {
            if (err) {
                return console.log(err);
            }
            cb(salt);
            bcrypt.hash(getit, salt, function (err, gotit) {
                if (err) throw err;
                return this.cb(null, gotit);
            })
        })
    }

    hashP(data.Lname, function (err, gotit) {
        if (err) throw err;
        data.Lname = hash;
    })

    console.log(data.Lname);
    con.query("insert into test set ?", [data], function (err, rows) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.send("Value has bee inserted");
    })
})
```

This is my html form page:

```
<body>
<form action="http://localhost:8888/insert" method="POST" >
    <label>Name:</label><input type="text" name="fname"></br>
    <label>Lname:</label><input type="text" name="Lname"></br>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: I've not got any error the data which is come from html form directly inserted into db. But it's not converted as encrypt data. And when i check in terminal i'm getting two Lname values one is direct data and another is encrypted data.

Comment: This looks wrong: `data.Lname = hash;` because `hash` is not defined anywhere.  Did you mean to use `gotit` instead?

Comment: yes mac u r right but data which is  coming from html has been encrypted but the encrypted valued doesn't store in db instead of that the html value is stored i think we ve to change the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your function `hashP(getit,cb)` is calling `cb` function at bad time isn't it? try the following

```
function hashP(getit, cb){
        bcrypt.genSalt(15, function (err, salt){
            if(err) {
                return cb(err, null);
            }
            bcrypt.hash(getit, salt, function (err, hash){
                if(err) {
                    return cb(err, null);
                }
                return cb(null, hash);
            })
        })
    }
```

Apart, you'll need to call it inside your handler as following:

```
app.post(...., function(req, res) {  

    var data = { ... }

    function hashP(data, cb){ ... }

    hashP(data.Lname, function (err, hash) {
      if (err) throw err;
      data.Lname = hash;
      // NOW, SAVE THE VALUE AT DB
      con.query("insert into test set ?", [data], function (err, rows) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.send("Value has bee inserted");
    })
  }
}
```

The problem here was **asynchronous execution**, you were calling `con.query` with `data` *before* `data` is returned from `hashP`

Comment: But encryption doesn't happen this way all i want to encrypt the data before it goes it to db.